Lost second nationality passport
I have dual UK and Sierra Leone citizenship. I submitted my expired UK passport with my also expired Sierra Leone passport in 2022, when I applied for a renewal UK passport. However they  both got lost in the mail, so I had to apply for a replacement UK passport. However I didn't apply for a new S.L. passport, and I have no details of the lost one to enter on my ESTA application. How can I proceed when there is no option on the form to explain the situation.

Doesn't it ask for such details of the passports as you have?  If you no longer have the details, you can't enter them.  You might be able to get them from the SL passport office; if you have time it's certainly worth a try.

Does the form allow you to enter eg your full name, DOB, place of birth etc and proceed without needing to enter the lost passport number? Do you have any old paperwork that might have details of the lost passport?

What exactly does the passport form say?

Why don't you get you SL passport replaced? At least you should notify the SL government it's lost, so it can be invalidated
